# Run Java Swing JFrame in PHP

Tags: java, php, swing, jframe

I want to know if it's possible and if yes how to do it. I got my server and I want to launch a java.jar file on my website, in PHP. I found the way to run jar file remotely on my PC from another one, but what I need to achieve is launching the jar that is on my PC(server) on user's PC in web browser window, so he can see everything and interact with it. I made the Java app `JFrame`.

If you need further info just ask, not sure what exactly is required here. And if you want to know what it is - simple game with mouse and keyboard control.

Answer (score 2):

A frame cannot be embedded in a web page, but can be launched from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

An applet (`JApplet`) could ..theoretically, be embedded into a web page.  That is, until a host of security scares had browser manufacturers adding extra browser related prompts prior to launching them, and Chrome as well as FireFox deciding they will be dropping all support for embedded applets.

To have any hope of being launched, either an embedded applet or an app. launched using JWS would need to be digitally signed using a certificate issued by a Certification Authority.

> ..simple game with mouse and keyboard control.

It may have been simple to code, and may be simple to play, but *deployment* is anything but simple.